# Regex matching specific value after a certain number of tabs

Tags: regex, perl

In a tab delimited text file, I would like to match only lines containing the "1" value right after the 24th tab.
Right now, the regex I have seems to match what I want, but breaks when the line doesn't match.
Could you help me improving it?

### My regex :

```
/(?:.+?\t){24}1/
```

### Sample input :

```
INT E_63    0   0   u   Le  Le  DET:ART DET le  ??  ADJ SENT DET:ART NOM ADV    SENT DET NOM    1   ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  0   0   0   0   0   1   ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  
INT E_63    0   0   u   Le  Le  DET:ART DET le  ??  ADJ SENT DET:ART NOM ADV    SENT DET NOM    1   ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  0   0   0   0   0   0   ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  ??
```

(The first line should match, the second should not.)

Comment: What does it mean "_breaks when the line doesn't match_" ... how does it break?

Comment: Try `/^(?:[^\t]*\t){24}1/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot it works perfectly ! With a little more explanation on what I did wrong and why this works, it would be a great answer.

Comment: `(split /\t/)[24] eq '1j'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex does not work when there is no match due to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) as `.` also matches a tab character. Coupled with the fact that there are more subpatterns after the group with nested quantifiers, and absence of the `^` anchor, the catastrophic backtracking is imminent.

What you need is a negated character class `[^\t]` and anchor the pattern at the start of the string:

```
/^(?:[^\t]*\t){24}1/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MfoyUn/1).

NOTE: To match the `1` as a whole word, you might consider adding `\b` after it, or a lookahead `(?!\S)`.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:[^\t]*\t){24}` - 24 sequences of

  - `[^\t]*` - 0+ chars other than a tab char
  - `\t`  - a tab char
- `1` - a `1` char.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using regex you could just split it, check the 24th column at 23rd index and then use conditionals.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $fh, "<", '/path/to/tab_delem_file') or die "Could not open file $!";

while(<$fh>){
  chomp;
  my @line = split/\t/, $_; #split on tab
  if ($line[23] == 1){
      #do something
  }
  else ($line[23] == 1){
      #do something else
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll accept Wicktor's answer as it is a direct answer to my question, but thanks for the alternative solution !

Comment: or simply `my $field = ( split /\t/ )[22]; if ( $field == 1 ) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: The field to be checked is the 25th - "the value right after the 24th tab"